# Log location of failed map task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

This is my failed map task, i just want to see logs of this failed task

```
15/10/31 11:51:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1446252902559_0009_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
```

Is there any way to check failed map task logs thanks

Answer (score 0):

From UI, you can go the job and individual map tasks, and go to the logs link. 
If you are using yarn, then it does the aggregation for you and save them in hdfs. You can use as follows:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>
```

Look [here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/) for complete log details

Comment: i want to see . . attempt_1446252902559_0009_m_000001_0 log of this . . not application log

Comment: Then you can get it from UI for that particular task. Mostly that task would have failed. If you know the container for that map task, the above command can take container id too. Ideally its better to catch exception and write the error message using System.err.println(msg)

Comment: Check http://<yarn-server>:19888/jobhistory to check the logs of all jobs/tasks/attempts.